# Downloading files from remote location using google openid authentication

Tags: python, perl, download, openid

i am looking to write a script either perl/python which can help me download files from the remote https server which needs google openid authentication,

i have the userid and password and am able to access and download the files from the browser, but i would like to know if someone could help me with a script which i can run to download the files locally to my PC

i am using ubuntu 11.04, and also have windows pc, i can send the specific details of the link if needed

please help me

Comment: Have you taken a look at the python url & url2 modules?

Comment: could you point me any examples, i am pretty new to programming or scripting, i would like to download a file from secured location which asks for google openid authentication, does the url and url2 modules give any procedure to pass the authentication?

Comment: i also tried using the wget and curl but none of them were helpful, any reference to command line method would also be very helpful,

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html

Comment: Since OP needs the openid login, the url-library will not help. You will need to code the login.

Comment: thanks for the headsup simbabque, i get that urllib wouldn't be able to pass through the openid, could you elobrate on your comment "You will need to code the login" , i also tried with the user and apitoken through which jenkins downloads the files, but the url keeps getting timed out when trying via wget

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try even [requestlib](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) Python library to do all the web-services tasks

```
requests.get()
```

Comment: @sandeep here you cant expect working code try yourself and we will be helping

Comment: dear naga, below is my sample code i am using to login to the redirected webpage, but i am unable to get logged in

Comment: i will post my code in an hour, i dont have enough points to post my answer before 8hours